# Why does my Android app say "This app is incompatible with all of your devices?" on the store?

Tags: google

I've published my app.  It's installed on my Nexus 5X.  Play console says 12,000+ devices compatible.  I've updated my gradle files.  People that install the APK say it works no problem.  What could be going on here?  Thanks!